# Выбрать clang-3.8 по умолчанию

Tags: clang

Убунту 12.04, установлено две версии компилятора 3 и 3.8. Как выбрать чтоб 3.8 был дефолтным?

> $ sudo update-alternatives --config clang
>
> update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for clang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Каким способом устанавливались две версии clang и какая из них сейчас присутствует в пути?

`which clang`

Сконфигурировать через update-alternatives - хорошая мысль, можно самостоятельно добавить запись:

`sudo update-alternatives --install $(which clang) clang /path/to/actual/binary 1000000`

1 000 000 - приоритет записи

Comment: 3 из родных реп, 3.8 из deb http://apt.llvm.org/precise/ llvm-toolchain-precise-3.8 main
deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/precise/ llvm-toolchain-precise-3.8 main. 
/usr/bin/clang и /usr/bin/clang-3.8

Comment: sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clang clang /usr/bin/clang-3.8 1000000

Comment: И sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clang++ clang++ /usr/bin/clang++-3.8 1000000 Спасибо=)